# VS 2013 error on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2013, winsxs

So I reinstalled several times Visual Studio 2013, and every time I get this error when I try to start it

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...
```

I ran a SXStrace debug, and this is the output file

```
    =================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\
    Application Config File = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Application Config File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config.
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is devenv,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="X86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: coloader80.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: debuggerproxy.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.CompilerHostObjectsProxy.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="X86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0__6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Auto Servicing Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.7601.17514".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.7601.17514".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en-US\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.7601.17514_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\en\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference coloader80.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\coloader80.dll.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\coloader80.dll.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\coloader80.dll\coloader80.dll.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\coloader80.dll\coloader80.dll.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference coloader80.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

What could be the problem? Don't know what other info to provide...
I also tried to run `sfc /scannow` but nothing changed

Comment: Why did you use a tag that says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!!"?

Comment: Very similar question with some solutions (none accepted as an answer though) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130609/visual-studio-2012-side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect

Comment: Lots of results on Google search and the common resolution seems to be to uninstall and re-install VS (repairing does not seems to work) - http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/visual-studio-2010-error

Comment: uninstalled it several times, still the same...
also checked the other answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked to register the file using regsvr32

```
regsvr32 "%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\coloader8O.dll"
```

! This needs to be ran with admin rights in cmd !

Comment: @Sartheris That's unfortunate, Did you download the original version from the visual studio website?

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer did you run the Webinstaller or the Disk image?

Comment: from the visual studio site I just downloaded a single file installer "vs_community" and it starts installing