# Mercurial side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: mercurial, side-by-side

I'm trying to install and run x64 Mercurial 3.8.3, but I'm getting the following error:

```
D:\Program Files\Mercurial>hg.exe
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

Running `sxstrace.exe` gives the following log:

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = D:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = D:\Program Files\Mercurial\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File D:\Program Files\Mercurial\hg.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_acd40623e1d81331.manifest
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

It seems like it's looking for `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_acd40623e1d81331.manifest`, which doesn't exist on my computer. I think this file comes from the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368), but when I installed/repaired it I still get the same error.

I've also come across this [same package from chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcredist2008), but its version history seems to indicate that its latest version is **9.0.30729.6161**, not the **9.0.30729.9177** I'm looking for. I'm not sure where to find this version of the package.

I've already looked at these questions which seem very similar to my situation:

- [Side by Side configuration is incorrect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779226/side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect-error)
- [Visual Studio 2012 Side by side configuration is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130609/visual-studio-2012-side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect)

**Edit:** I've just reinstalled with x86 Mercurial and it works. Not ideal, but at least it's a workaround.

Comment: Where did you get the package you're trying to install? I might be able to direct you to a useful mailing list.

Comment: @durin42 I honestly don't know how 9.0.30729.9177 got on my computer. This is the most troubling part. [My most recent lead](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3774a186-8151-433a-8122-db58d55b7af2/how-to-revert-an-old-msvcr90dll) suggests that this happened automatically.

Comment: 9.anything isn't a plausible version number for Mercurial - the latest hg release is 3.8.3, so I'm confused where that version number comes from. It'll be hard to help if I don't know what that version number means.

Comment: Version 9.whatever refers to the version of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package. The version of Mercurial I'm trying to install is 3.8.3. I'll update the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package 9.0.30729.9177 doesn't seem to be publicly available, so I ended up reinstalling Windows. Now I can run Mercurial after installing it.